# Split DateTime into two Textboxs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have been combing the web for a helper method that will split a datetime into two textboxes one for date and one for time so I can use javascript on them.

Anyone know where I can find one? Closest I've been able to come is shown below but that separates into five fields.

```
  def datetime_text_fields(object_name, method)

      html = text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(3i)]", Date.today.day.to_s, :length => 2)
      html = text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(2i)]", Date.today.day.to_s, :length => 2)
      html << text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(1i)]", Date.today.year.to_s, :length => 4)
      html << " "
      html << text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(4i)]", Time.now.hour.to_s, :length => 2)
      html << ":"
      html << text_field_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}(5i)]", Time.now.min.to_s, :length => 2)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is what you are looking for.
In controllers you can do something like this:

```
@time = Time.now
time = @time.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
date = @time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
```

Or In Your View you can do something like this:

```
<h3><%= @time.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></h3>
<h3><%= @time.strftime("%I:%M %p") %></h3>
```

Comment: I tried something like this at first however it doesn't seem to work with validation on forms.